# How to test three.js tutorial in the View of CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, three.js, scene

I get stuck when try to insert a demo of three.js tutorial into the view of CakePHP,
This demo (creating a scene): [enter link description here](http://threejs.org/docs/#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene)

Has anybody try it like that ?
Thanks for reading . I hope you share your experiments.

Detail my problems:

---

1. I create webgl_test.js and put it into ...webroot/js/, and also put the three.min.js into webroot/js/

```js
//------------- CREATING THE SCENE-----------------------
    /* To actually be able to display anything with Three.js, we need three things: 
    1. A Scene
    2. A Camera
    3. A Renderer so we can render the scene with the camera
    */
    
    var main=function() {
        var CANVAS=document.getElementById("your_canvas");
    
        var scene =  new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias  : true,
        canvas : CANVAS
        });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        //document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);  //we add the renderer element to our HTML document
    
        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry (2,1,1);
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ({color: 0x00ffff});
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh (geometry, material);
        scene.add(cube);
    
        camera.position.z = 5;
    
    //-------------RENDERING THE SCENE------------------------
        function render(){
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
    
            cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
            cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        render();
    };
```

2. In the header of default.ctp, I call script's library like that

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/webgl_test.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/three.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

3. Last step, I write some lines to show `<canvas>` element as below:

```html
<div>
       <ul>
            <li onload='main()'>                              
              <canvas id='your_canvas'style='position: absolute;'></canvas>
            </li>
       </ul>
 </div>
```

Then, It show nothing :((